# Discord dm by user id AUTO

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I maked some searchs and didn't find a way or something good to help me...
I wanna make a bot in python that send a DM to the User's ID's that i have. I looked for the Discord api py, but didn't understanded how can make the function to send message.

Comment: So, i don't have the permission to put the bot-member like a admin. What i want its like a normal member, but in python to send message to every user id that i have

Comment: A bot can't send a message to a user if you don't share a server with that user. you have to put the bot in the server like an admin

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to DM a user in [discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py).

If you want to message the user who ran the command, you can use `ctx.author.send`:

```
@client.command()
async def send(ctx):
   await ctx.author.send("Hi there")
```

To message a specific user:

```
@client.command()
async def send(ctx, user : discord.Member):
   await user.send("Hello")
```

Note: The `user` parameter can be either an @mention or, in your case, a user ID.

Comment: So, but isn't with a bot. It's to a channel that i'm not adm and has only the users id

Comment: A few things. First, to invite a bot to a server, you must have manage server permissions. Second of all, if this isn't with a bot, there is no way to automatically message users

Comment: I know that, but its for a other server that i don't has acess and can't give permissions.

Comment: If the bot does not share a server with the users you want to message, you cannot message them through the bot. Otherwise, just run the send command I put in my answer with the user ID as the user parameter.

Comment: But what i want its to send message like a normal account to the users id that I had

Comment: Using a regular account as a bot is called a "self-bot" and is against Discord Terms of Service. Creating and using a self-bot can result in account termination. See [this article](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-) for more information.

Comment: Fine, i know that... but how i can make this? Can u help me ?

Comment: This is something you may want to make a new question for, though I highly discourage going down the self-bot path. There are many other questions and online articles on making self-bots that you can follow, but because of the ban on them , I probably should not help.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-dm).  Just do something like

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def send(ctx,user:discord.Member):
await user.send("Hello User"!)
```